# I want to store value from the loop which i had used in check_output(). I want to store value of %a in variable x. so is there any way?

Tags: python, image-processing, operating-system, subprocess, face-recognition

I want to store value of %a in some variable(x). so is there any method of any library?
Basically i want to store a value and use it fr if-else statement.

```
#x = subprocess.check_output("face_recognition ./img/known ./img/unknown1 | awk '{ print $2 }'", shell=True)

d = subprocess.check_output("for /f \"tokens=2,* delims=,\" %a in ('face_recognition ./img/known ./img/unknown1') do x   = %a", shell=True)
#x = d.decode('ASCII')
#z = subprocess.check_call(x,shell=True)
print(x)
#print(x)
y = 'unknown_person'
if x != y:
     #print(x)
    print("Hello! stranger. my self DVJRAM")
```

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)